# R Reactable hide columns by default

Tags: r, reactable

I would like to display a dataframe consisting on many columns in a reactable. Since only very few columns are interesting the default setting should be to hide the columns. When I do this it is however impossible to see any columns since none are displayed at all. What is the correct way to do this?

```
library(reactable)
reactable(mtcars,
          defaultColDef = colDef(show = F),
          columns = list(
            mpg = colDef(show =T)
          ))
```

In this case no columns are displayed despite `mpg` being set to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you want to do is use `defaultColDef` to "hide" all columns NOT explicitly assigned for display.  This can be done by assigning `defaultColDef` last:

```
library(reactable)
reactable(mtcars,
      columns = list(
        mpg = colDef(show =T)),
      defaultColDef = colDef(show = F)
      )
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to display mpg column, you can simply subset this column in reactable:

```
reactable(mtcars[0:1],
          defaultColDef = colDef(show = T))
```